# Convert string to double with default value

Tags: .net, vb.net, parsing, type-conversion, default

How to convert a string to double with a default value using a native method?

Something like this?

```
dim value as double
dim text

value = Double.TryParse(text, 0)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do it in one line:

```
Dim value as Double
Dim text="23.675"

If Not Double.TryParse(text, value) Then value = 4
'At this point value contains either the parsed value of text 
'or 4 if text couldn't be parsed into a double
```

Docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1(v=vs.110).aspx

You could of course make a method to do this with a default value:

```
Public Function TryParseDoubleDefault(text as String, defaultValue as Double) As Double
    Dim parsedValue As Double
    If Not Double.TryParse(text, parsedValue) Then parsedValue = defaultValue
    Return parsedValue
End Function
```

And you could even make this an extension method of Double:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function TryParseDefault(aDouble As Double, text as String, defaultValue as Double) As Double
    Dim parsedValue As Double
    If Not Double.TryParse(text, parsedValue) Then parsedValue = defaultValue
    Return parsedValue
End Function
```

so that you could then just do this as you originally wanted:

```
value = Double.TryParseDefault(text, 4)
```

Comment: If you need it a lot, write the Extension.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim text As String = "123.45"
Dim value As Double
If Double.TryParse(text, value) Then
    ' text is convertible to Double, and value contains the Double value now
Else
    ' Cannot convert text to Double set the default value here 
End If
```